# custom NgbDateAdapter to show date from NgbDatepicker in specific TimeZone

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I have ngbDatePicker that works normally.
I use

```
{
  provide: NgbDateAdapter,
  useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter,
}
```

as a provider in my component.

What i want to achieve is via some custom DateAdapter to show a date in a specific time Zone.
Now the date is shown accordingly to the user TimeZone.
So if a date is lets say 02.01.2000 with GMT +2 Germany, the users in San Francisco will see 01.01.2000.

Is there any way to create a custom Adapter, that shows the date in the date picker of one and only one specific time zone, ignoring the time zone of the user in the browser?

Thanks